# My new website links will not appear

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, hyperlink

I just uploaded a new website, and for the life of me I can not figure out why my links in the main body of the site do not work.  The words and or images show up, but they are not clickable and the cursor will not change to acknowledge they are links.

The targets appear to be right in Chrome Developer Tools, and the HREF is correct.

The HTML:

```
  <ul id='portfolioLinks'>
                    <li><a href="http://www.uhmgotzonwrestling.com">Uhmgotz on  Wrestling</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Villa Ave</a></li>
                    <li><a href='http://github.com/TomSchinler'>GitHub</a></li>
                    <li><a href='http://stackoverflow.com/users/3712998/t-schinler'>Stack Overflow</a></li>
                    <li><a href='http://teamtreehouse.com/tomschinler'>Team Treehouse</a></li>
                    <li><a href='http://www.linkedin.com/in/tomschinler/'>LinkedIn</a></li>
                    <li><a href='http://www.facebook.com/tom.schinler'>FaceBook</a></li>
                    <li><a href='http://twitter.com/TommyUhmgotz'>Twitter</a></li>

                </ul>
```

The CSS:

```
   #siteLinks {
     float:left;
     width:19%;
     height:550px;
     text-align: center;
     z-index: 1;
   }
```

The site is [TomSchinler.com](http://www.tomschinler.com).  All of the site code is available on my Git-Hub profile here : [Git-Hub](http://github.com/TomSchinler/Resume).  Please help me if at all possible.

Comment: its your css, i'll let you work out the specifics

Comment: Don't link to live pages. Instead, post the relevant sections of your code here, so that it may benefit future users in case the pages you linked to change or die.

Comment: +@esqew or to some place where the code didn't change when you solve it, like jsfiddle or similar.

Comment: Thank you for the posting tips.  I have edited the question to include relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed style with Chrome Developer Tools and it worked. Add <kbd>z-index</kbd> property in CSS.

Change this

```
#siteLinks {
    float: left;
    width: 19%;
    height: 550px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

With this

```
#siteLinks {
    float: left;
    width: 19%;
    height: 550px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First.. the code and example..
Set a working example in some place where the code didn't dissapear when you fix the problem.

Then, looking at your code, you have a `layer position` problem:
The `#threehouse > .treehouse` is OVER your `#siteLinks` so even if the links are ok, they are not accesible with the mouse pointer.

Change or fix the CSS will solve your problem.
If you can't repair the entirly file, just add a `z-index` property to `#siteLinks` to be over the rest.

```
#siteLinks {
    z-index: 1;
}
```